# $2$-variable integer program with equality constraint

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

I have an integer program with variables $x, y \in \{0,1,\dots,m\}$. Somehow, I can prove that

1. the cost function will strictly decrease with both $x$ and $y$.
2. an optimal solution should satisfy $x+y=k$.

Do I still need to do linear search over $x \in \{0,1,\dots,k\}$? Or are there other simpler solutions?

ADD: I am wondering if I can substitute $y$ with $k-x$ so that the original problem is reduced to integer programming with just one variable $x$. Let's say the cost function becomes $f(x)$. And by computation, $f(x)$ will be minimized at $x^*$. Can I just search around $x^*$ and get the optimal solution?

Comment: How can you search "around $x^*$" when $x^*$ is unknown and is the solution ?

Comment: I am thinking the cost function is reduced to a one-dimensional function $f(x)$. So I can minimize $f(x)$ first to get $x^*$ (and $k-x^*$). Then I ASSUME that the optimal solution is around $(x^*,k-x^*)$. So I can just search around $(x^*,k-x^*)$. But I am not sure if the assumption is right or not.

Comment: Don't you realize that the optimal solution *is* $(x^*,k-x^*)$ ? So your proposal amounts to: 1) find the optimal solution, then 2) search in the vicinity of the optimal solution.

Comment: That's exactly my question. Can we guarantee that the optimal integer solution is in the vicinity of $(x^*,k-x^*)$?

Comment: In the end I understood what you mean. In your mind, $x^*$ is not integer and you find it with an "ordinary" solver (assuming that by some magic you can solve for the continuous case). Then this is a bad idea because the integer solution may very well be far from the continuous solution.

Comment: Thanks for your illustration. I understand that point. But I am still considering a special case. That is, we can prove that, in the continuous case, $f(x)$ will strictly decrease as $x$ increases.  We can then get the continuous optimal result $(x^*, k-x^*)$. Then can we say that the optimal integer solution is in the vicinity of $(x^*, k-x^*)$? The plot in your illustration does not apply to this special case.

Comment: You never said that $f(x)$ is decreasing (or you wrongly think that $f(x)$ is decreasing). And if it is, the optimal integer solution is perforce the last value. Stop the nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is of course better to eliminate one of the unknowns to get a one-dimensional problem.

Anyway, when doing so, $c(x, k-x)$ loses the montonicity property and it is not even sure that it is unimodal. So exhaustive search is safer.

---

**Update:**

The integer minimum might not coincide with the continuous minimum. For the sake of illustration:

[image]

Comment: so, as described in the problem, the optimal solution is not guaranteed to be near $(x^*,k-x^*)$?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have more information about the cost function such as a discrete differential equation there is no simpler way.

I am assuming $m\geq k$ and that you are looking for *the* optimal solution and not *a* pseudo-optimal solution.

Comment: The first order discrete differential equation (regarding both $x$ and $y$) is strictly less than 0. So I am claiming that the cost function will decrease with both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Yes, but it seems that you have no been given any information on the relation between the discrete partial derivatives of x and y. So without that I don't see any other option.

Comment: Response to the edit in your question: To find $x^*$ you would have to be given $f(x)$ or  $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$, making the solution trivial so I'm assuming you were not given these.